# deleting entity by ID fails

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to delete a record by its primary key:

```
var doc = new MyDoc { DocId = doc_id };
data.Docs.Attach(doc);
data.Docs.Remove(doc);
```

the call to `Attach` fails with the error below. Would someone please help me figure out what is wrong?

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `Doc` with this Id from `DbContext`. So you cannot attach new `Doc` with this `Id` to `DbContext`. You have to possible cases:
Find `Doc` that you get with this Id or close `DbContext` and open new `DbContext`, then attach.